# Ruby: Remove number from embedded string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a Rails app I am reading a file with key/values. An index number is embedded in the key name, and I'd like to remove it, along with one of the spacing underscores.

So in the sample data below, I'd like to convert:

- `PRIMER_LEFT_1_END_STABILITY` into `PRIMER_LEFT_END_STABILITY`
- `PRIMER_RIGHT_1_END_STABILITY` into `PRIMER_RIGHT_END_STABILITY`
- `PRIMER_PAIR_1_COMPL_ANY_TH` into `PRIMER_PAIR_COMPL_ANY_TH`

#### Sample Data

```
PRIMER_LEFT_1_END_STABILITY=7.2000

PRIMER_RIGHT_1_END_STABILITY=7.9000

PRIMER_PAIR_1_COMPL_ANY_TH=0.00
```

---

#### EDIT

Thanks to @tihom for the first answer. It's partially working, but I did not specify that the embedded integer can be of any value. When over 1 digit in length the regex fails:

```
1.9.3-p327 :003 > "PRIMER_LEFT_221_END_STABILITY".sub(/_\d/,"")
 => "PRIMER_LEFT21_END_STABILITY"
1.9.3-p327 :004 > "PRIMER_LEFT_21_END_STABILITY".sub(/_\d/,"")
 => "PRIMER_LEFT1_END_STABILITY"
```

Comment: I've posted a bounty for the entire problem: https://bountify.co/load-rails-table-from-text-file

Comment: What should be the output of `PRIMER_LEFT_1_END_STABILITY=7.2000` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the first occurrence  use `sub` else to remove all occurrences use `gsub`

```
"PRIMER_LEFT_1_END_STABILITY".sub(/_(\d)+/,"") # => "PRIMER_LEFT_END_STABILITY"
```

"+" matches one or more of the preceding character. So in this case it matches one or more of any digit followed by a "_"

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I've added additional details in EDIT above

Comment: Thank you @tihom. So the "+" checks for additional digits?

Comment: "+" matches one or more of a character

Answer (score 1):

You can use [***`String#tr`***](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-tr) and [***`String#squeeze`***](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-squeeze)as below :

```
ar=['PRIMER_LEFT_1_END_STABILITY','PRIMER_RIGHT_1_END_STABILITY','PRIMER_PAIR_1_COMPL_ANY_TH']
p ar.map{|s| s.tr('0-9','').squeeze("_")}
# => ["PRIMER_LEFT_END_STABILITY", "PRIMER_RIGHT_-END_STABILITY", "PRIMER_PAIR_COMPL_ANY_TH"]


ar=["PRIMER_LEFT_221_END_STABILITY","PRIMER_LEFT_21_END_STABILITY"]
p ar.map{|s| s.tr('0-9','').squeeze("_")}
# => ["PRIMER_LEFT_END_STABILITY", "PRIMER_LEFT_END_STABILITY"]
```

Comment: Hi @Arup thanks for your answer. It's almost there... should be PRIMER_LEFT_END_STABILITY rather than PRIMER_LEFT__END_STABILITY. That is a single underscore. I tried to fix it myself but am losing all underscores.

Comment: I like that! The squeeze function. Thank you!